# XSS: REQUEST_URI run through htmlspecialchars() - then replacing &amp; with & - enough to prevent XSS injection?

Tags: php, javascript, xss, htmlspecialchars

**Scenario:**

I would like to replace: `" ' < >` with `&quot; &#039; &lt; &gt;` **but keep the "&" character**.

The string I'm dealing with is a URL and I want URL parameters to be separated by `&`, not `&amp;`.

**Example Solution:**

```
$url = "/some/path?a=123&b=456"; // from $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 
$url = htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1', true); 
$url = str_replace('&amp;','&',$url);
```

**Question:**

If I use `$url` on my page (e.g. `echo $url;` inside HTML or JavaScript) can this be exploited by XSS?

**Similar Questions:**

> There are other posts on SO covering
>   XSS & `htmlspecialchars()` but I can't
>   find an answer around whether the "&"
>   character (and the htmlentities it may
>   allow) can expose you to XSS.
>
> - [Is replacing : < and > with &lt; and &gt; enough to prevent XSS injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113984/is-replacing-and-with-lt-and-gt-enough-to-prevent-xss-injection)
> - [is htmlspecialchars() in PHP or h() in Ruby on Rails good enough for defending all cases of XSS (Cross-site scripting) attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861781/is-htmlspecialchars-in-php-or-h-in-ruby-on-rails-good-enough-for-defending-al)

Comment: Is the URL acquired from user data?

Comment: In my case URL is taken from $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ... basically anything entered into the browser address bar.

Answer (score 1):

**Sijmen Ruwhof** made this interesting point that I feel is relevant:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php#99896

> The 'ENT_QUOTES' option doesn't
>   protect you against javascript
>   evaluation in certain tag's
>   attributes, like the 'href' attribute
>   of the 'a' tag. When clicked on the
>   link below, the given JavaScript will
>   get executed:

```
<?php
$_GET['a'] = 'javascript:alert(document.cookie)';
$href = htmlEntities($_GET['a'], ENT_QUOTES);
print "<a href='$href'>link</a>"; # results in: <a href='javascript:alert(document.cookie)'>link</a>
?>
```

Comment: Since the source of his data is REQUEST_URI, it is impossible that a request starts with `javascript:`. It will always start with a `/` which makes this vector impossible to use.

Comment: You're right HoLyVier. My answer here is more in regard to htmlspecialchars() not always being enough to prevent XSS injection... Not totally relevant to my "REQUEST_URI" question; but hopefully still useful information to others.

Answer (score 0):

I once used really weird code for escaping urls, but I bet this can be done better, furthermore this does not cover the html specialchars yet, it was just used for saving urls to the database.

```
function escapeUrl(&$url){
 $matches = parse_url($url);
    if(!isset($matches["host"])){
        Utils_Logging_Logger::getLogger()->log(
            "Unknown host for URL: \"$url\".",
            Utils_Logging_Logger::TYPE_ERROR
       );
       $matches["host"] = "";
    }
    if(!isset($matches["scheme"])){
        Utils_Logging_Logger::getLogger()->log(
            "Sheme (like http://) for URL: \"$url\" was not set.",
            Utils_Logging_Logger::TYPE_LOG);
        $url = "http://";
    }else{$url = $matches["scheme"]."://";}
    $url.=$matches["host"];
    if(isset($matches["path"])){
        $path = rawurldecode($matches["path"]);
        $url.=$path;   
    }
    if(isset($matches["query"])){
        $query = rawurldecode($matches["query"]);
        $url.="?".$query;
    }
    return $url;
```

}